# create custom culture and register it to local machine powershell

Tags: powershell

is it possible to create custom culture with powershell??
I have seen examples using .NET and C# and wondering if powershell can do the same. I can only be able to show cultures from my computer but not able to create a custom one with powershell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sample from the [`CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder` class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.90).aspx) on msdn is easily translated to PowerShell.

I, for example, would like to use the Danish Krone as default currency, but otherwise US culture info options:

```
$CultureName = 'x-my-culture'
$BaseCulture = [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US')
$BaseRegion = New-Object System.Globalization.RegionInfo 'US'
$Changes = @{
    CurrencyEnglishName = 'Danish Krone'
    CurrencyNativeName = 'Dansk Krone'
    ISOCurrencySymbol = 'DKK'
}

try
{
    # Set up CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder
    Add-Type -AssemblyName sysglobl
    $CultureBuilder = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder @($CultureName,[System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionModifiers]::None)
    $CultureBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo($BaseCulture)
    $CultureBuilder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo($BaseRegion)


    # Make appropriate changes
    foreach($Property in $Changes.Keys){
        $CultureBuilder.$Property = $Changes[$Property]
    }

    # Register your new culture
    $CultureBuilder.Register()

}
catch
{
    throw
}
```

To unregister the custom culture again, use the static `Unregister()` method:

```
[System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder]::Unregister('x-my-culture')
```

Comment: Which version of Powershell did you test this with? In Powershell 7.3.2 this code fails with the following message: `Exception calling "LoadDataFromCultureInfo" with "1" argument(s): "Field
     | 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo.m_cultureData' not found."`

Comment: @Crono Given the date of this answer: 5.1 :)